# SVN: How to keep a Branch in Synch with Trunk?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

Is there a way to keep a specific branch in synch with Trunk, that is, every time someone checks code into trunk, that code will be also sent to a particular Branch?

We have a situation where we are having to make new branches based off of Trunk every time a new release is made. The reason is that we are migrating to a new environment but we are in the dev phase of that environment and se we have to keep the current trunk active, but we need to make new branches for the new environment because that code fork conforms to the new environment.

In effect we have two parallel trunks, but the second one in dev has to be recreated every time by merging the main trunk.

We're wondering if we can set SVN to copy the changes checked into main trunk over to the parallel dev "trunk".

I know, it is confusing, sorry.

By the way, this is NOT GIT SVN, just regular SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Post-commit hook, which, internally:

- Check node, affected by commit (`svnlook dirs-changed`)
- If it's `/trunk`, `svn copy && svn commit` changes